# Partial upgrade from 12.04 now can't boot

Tags: boot, partial-upgrade

I went through the process of running a partial upgrade in 12.04, now when I reboot, I get stuck at a black screen with a cursor. Any help? I have reinstalled nvidia drivers by going through the terminal but the problem still persists!

Answer (score 0):

1st option : get a CD including Boot-Repair

2nd option : install Boot-Repair in Ubuntu

```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && 

  sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```